# mbstring module install redhat apache

Tags: php, apache, mbstring

I have a machine with no internet access and want to install mbstring module for apache with Redhat OS

I can't use yum install, and i can't find the ./configure file that mentioned in many answers for the same question.

downloaded the rpm file and installed it but with no luck.

Can someone provide me with step by step installion for the module ?

Comment: apache has no mbstring module. You mean the mbstring module for PHP? Download the rpm on some OTHER device and then transfer it to your server.

Comment: I did .. installed the rpm file .. the module not shown in the phpinfo .php file when i browse it and not in php -m commend

Comment: did you restart apache? did you check the php.ini file to make sure it's properly linked in?

Comment: Yes apache restart and here is the end of my php.ini file

extension=mbstring.so
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6

Answer (score 0):

It's located in the "optional" repo. Have your sysadmin enable this repo. This may help you a few steps further.

`$ sudo yum list php-mbstring`

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite. Installed Packages php-mbstring.x86_64      
    5.3.3-23.el6_4                     @rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6
```